# Dividir arrays conociendo el largo que se necesita obtener

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una petición a través de una `API` de la `NASA`, para obtener una información, pero los datos retornados a través de esta es largo, debido a que cada uno corresponde a cada día del año.

Depende el año, sea bisiesto *(366 días)* o no *(365 días)*, me llega informacion, la cual accedo, son objetos y *arrays*, pero debido a que es muy largo, no sabia que el máximo largo que permitía era de **100** valores dentro de un `array`.

#### Array

> (365) [5.34, 5.68, 5.59, 5.52, 5.42, 4.32, 4.48, 3.68, 3.93, 4.79, 5.74, 4.26, 3.2, 5.26, 5.34, 4.97, 5.21, 5.13, 5.3, 5.07, 5.26, 4.99, 5.36, 5.26, 4.54, 5.99, 6.18, 5.96, 5.47, 4.9, 4.19, 5.66, 5.17, 5.53, 4.88, 5.12, 5.65, 5.38, 5.06, 4.9, 5.64, 5.01, 4.4, 5.44, 5.88, 6.3, 5.5, 6.38, 6.48, 6.58, 6.08, 6.49, 5.4, 6.15, 6.66, 6.67, 6.23, 5.8, 6.26, 5.6, 6.25, 4.85, 3.73, 4.49, 3.69, 3.43, 5.09, 4.64, 5.73, 5.48, 5.22, 5.72, 6.65, 5.47, 6.63, 6.15, 6.22, 6.03, 6.58, 6.28, 6.24, 3.22, 2.16, 5.69, 5.72, 5.02, 5.86, 5.22, 4.53, 5.81, 4.86, 6.41, 6.51, 6.45, 6.67, 6.44, 6.61, 5.42, 5.16, 6.21, …]

```
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]
[200 … 299]
[300 … 364]
length: 365
```

El vector de termina dividiendo en 4 vectores, 3 con 100 valores cada uno, y un ultimo con 64. Quisiera saber como obtener los valores dependiendo la cantidad de días por mes, teniendo estos como referente constante.

#### Ejemplo

**Enero**:*(31 días)*

La idea es tomar los primeros 31 valores del primer `array`**[0...99]**, y poder asignarlos, o sea, solo tomar estos valores, **[0...30]**.

[image: vectores]

Comment: chrome los divide en la consola para ayudar al usuario a ver los datos, el arreglo sigue teniendo el largo original

Comment: el problema no es manejalos en el cliente el problema es al enviarlo a una longitud maxima para hacer post apache tiene un [maximo de longitud](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) igual son configurables dependiendo de tu backend y como dice @Klaimmore la longitud es 365 puedes verlo al final de tu respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, el array siempre mantiene su largo original. En la consola se presenta en grupos de 100, pero eso es un detalle que puedes ignorar.

Lo que yo haría sería construir un arreglo de meses con su nombre y cantidad de días. Si vienen 366 datos en la respuesta, seteo el mes de febrero a 29 días.

Luego hago un `forEach` sobre el arreglo de meses y dentro del bucle retiro tantos elementos del array como días tenga el mes usando `Array.splice`.

```js
var meses=[
{nombre:'ene',dias:31},
{nombre:'feb',dias:28},
{nombre:'mar',dias:31},
{nombre:'abr',dias:30},
{nombre:'may',dias:31},
{nombre:'jun',dias:30},
{nombre:'jul',dias:31},
{nombre:'ago',dias:31},
{nombre:'sep',dias:30},
{nombre:'oct',dias:31},
{nombre:'nov',dias:30},
{nombre:'dic',dias:31}
];
var respuesta = [7.65, 4.71, 8.93, 8.04, 2.91, 5.32, 5.34, 3.19, 5.70, 2.48, 5.21, 6.98, 9.48, 2.52, 7.9, 5.69, 3.0, 9.58, 6.35, 3.99, 2.16, 2.02, 4.83, 7.39, 1.08, 8.18, 4.89, 2.09, 2.43, 1.96, 7.2, 1.71, 5.70, 6.8, 8.03, 2.20, 2.71, 9.11, 1.45, 2.82, 8.12, 2.59, 5.64, 6.03, 4.76, 8.24, 8.00, 9.7, 9.88, 4.98, 7.36, 8.14, 8.29, 2.61, 2.7, 6.14, 4.38, 5.13, 1.74, 4.37, 8.75, 5.67, 1.13, 9.07, 7.95, 9.67, 1.67, 8.83, 1.20, 7.15, 5.74, 6.48, 1.72, 1.11, 4.67, 8.73, 7.64, 3.70, 8.55, 3.02, 1.75, 3.00, 8.2, 3.41, 2.41, 4.09, 7.24, 5.17, 4.4, 7.7, 9.99, 2.93, 6.96, 4.77, 2.53, 4.52, 6.1, 8.39, 1.07, 7.94, 7.73, 6.27, 7.42, 6.44, 6.30, 6.63, 2.96, 6.72, 4.45, 1.47, 7.95, 6.76, 6.35, 3.66, 4.6, 9.82, 5.55, 7.87, 5.35, 7.93, 2.68, 3.69, 4.47, 2.22, 9.00, 6.92, 1.00, 5.31, 4.09, 7.24, 6.92, 5.06, 4.66, 7.72, 3.04, 9.05, 6.2, 8.21, 6.50, 9.81, 2.99, 4.06, 5.2, 5.4, 7.32, 4.78, 1.64, 5.87, 3.81, 5.02, 5.50, 6.37, 3.26, 6.10, 3.54, 5.29, 2.14, 6.05, 3.69, 5.96, 7.97, 4.49, 9.69, 4.48, 4.20, 1.30, 4.7, 8.98, 7.73, 1.68, 1.87, 8.97, 9.9, 1.41, 8.86, 2.12, 1.73, 7.87, 5.78, 5.69, 6.71, 9.70, 9.81, 5.24, 7.82, 7.27, 3.12, 7.79, 1.94, 4.74, 8.4, 8.91, 9.4, 7.75, 8.41, 5.03, 5.63, 8.91, 1.62, 5.56, 6.66, 5.14, 1.80, 4.93, 3.60, 2.21, 1.20, 6.13, 6.47, 2.08, 5.23, 9.98, 9.01, 2.56, 9.43, 7.96, 6.59, 3.63, 4.07, 4.27, 5.27, 5.60, 8.15, 9.89, 7.81, 9.1, 9.73, 4.53, 2.39, 9.6, 9.07, 9.14, 7.37, 3.94, 8.61, 6.72, 1.60, 8.02, 8.6, 7.71, 9.78, 4.63, 5.40, 4.93, 7.54, 4.19, 9.49, 1.44, 2.48, 3.67, 5.72, 2.25, 5.99, 1.10, 3.53, 4.70, 6.44, 3.13, 6.12, 4.78, 4.87, 1.24, 6.12, 4.90, 5.35, 8.75, 8.24, 6.96, 5.66, 5.5, 7.19, 6.04, 8.28, 4.87, 2.92, 3.80, 9.33, 8.24, 2.40, 7.68, 4.87, 1.06, 6.09, 5.05, 1.88, 5.55, 5.70, 2.62, 1.70, 9.78, 7.74, 7.06, 9.49, 2.19, 7.67, 1.70, 3.94, 4.48, 1.58, 1.10, 3.84, 6.38, 2.39, 7.74, 9.53, 8.00, 5.99, 4.06, 6.3, 2.14, 6.44, 7.23, 9.09, 1.68, 5.43, 4.87, 5.94, 1.12, 8.69, 1.62, 4.89, 2.22, 8.1, 6.59, 6.51, 7.5, 3.0, 2.80, 8.07, 2.93, 5.81, 6.47, 1.35, 7.87, 7.77, 3.77, 3.38, 5.15, 7.94, 6.2, 2.69, 6.49, 8.89, 4.41, 8.19, 9.02, 7.52, 7.04, 9.2, 9.54, 3.9, 9.89, 3.77, 3.55, 7.49, 7.62, 4.54, 3.33, 5.79, 8.23, 3.97, 9.17, 6.16, 9.42, 9.03, 4.41];

if(respuesta.length===366) {
meses[1].dias=29;
};

meses.forEach(function(mes) {
 var dias=mes.dias;
 mes.datos=respuesta.splice(0,dias);
 mes.cant_datos=mes.datos.length;
});

console.log(meses);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función [`Array#slice`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) de Javascript, la cual debes indicar el índice donde quieres empezar y el largo del array que necesitas obtener.

Ejemplo:

```
var enero = vector.slice(0, 31)
//enero tendrá los 31 primeros valores del vector original
```

Comment: Las respuestas deben ir acompañadas de un ejemplo práctico de código idealmente siguiendo la muestra de código que hace el OP

Comment: Gracias, haré la corrección requerida

Comment: y por curiosidad como sabe cuantos dias tiene enero y febrero.. si es biciesto... metele mas logica!!

Comment: Realmente solo se necesitaba el mes de enero, ya que Pedro en su pregunta especifica que ya sabe si el año es bisiesto y la cantidad de días de los meses...

Comment: Perdón por demorar tanto en responder, voy a probar esto. Gracias por todo, y pues claro si es bisiesto, el único mes que aumenta un valor es febrero el resto es igual.